# Use the text value in the Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I apologize for typing in English. This is a translator's achievement.
I want to come up with this formula but I can't.
A1 cell value is variable and can be one of these signs (=, <=,> =, <,>).
A3 and A4 cells also have numerical values.
Now the formula I am looking for in cell A2.

```
= if (A3 & A1 & A4,1,0)
```

So logical text can be one of the following:
A3 = A4 , A3 < A4 , A3 > A4 , A3 >= A4 , A3 <= A4
Is there a way for this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with formula one must do all the combinations:

```
=IF(CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"=","<=",">=","<",">"},0),A3=A4, A3<=A4,A3>=A4, A3<A4,A3>A4),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this method worked.
Your answer was closer to my wish.
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Nice!  My first thoughts when I saw the question was "no way that could be done!" but since there were a limited number of operands, your "case statement" is great!

Answer (score 1):

We need an extra step.  In **A2** enter:

```
="=if(A3" & A1 & "A4 ,1,0)"
```

Example:

[image]

Sadly **A2** is only a string and not a formula, but we can execute it.  In a standard module, enter the following User Defined Function:

```
Function eval(s As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    eval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

Pick another cell, say **B2** and enter:

```
=eval(A2)
```

[image]

Whenever **A1** or **A3** or **A4** are changed, the string-formula in **A2** will change and the value in **B2** will be re-calculated.

Comment: Excellent, this method worked
Thanks for answering.Your answer is more comprehensive, but  @scott craner answer is more efficient for me because I don't use modules.  
Overall both are great.